# WCF POST/GET method with parameters does not return any value

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

i have deployed my wcf service(dot NET) on IIS. When I call the service for an API with one parameter it does not return anything  . Interestingly this happens only if the the API I call has parameters . We are calling the webservice from a PHP file . And we give the link of PHP to the client(javascript).

Following is my web.config

> ```
>     <!-- Service Endpoints -->
>     <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
>     <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="Web">
>       <!-- 
>           Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
>           identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
>           automatically.
>       -->
>      </endpoint>
>     <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
>     <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
>     <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
>     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
>   </service>
> </services>
> <behaviors>
>   <serviceBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
>       <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
>       set the values below to false before deployment -->
>       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
>       <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
>       set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
>       to avoid disclosing exception information -->
>       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
>     </behavior>
>   </serviceBehaviors>
>   <endpointBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="Web">
>       <webHttp/>
>     </behavior>
>   </endpointBehaviors>
> </behaviors>   </system.serviceModel>
> <system.webServer>
>     <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
> </system.webServer> </configuration>
> ```

Following is the contact in my webservices

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://xomw764dei.dsone.3ds.com/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc")]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/getData", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, Method = "GET")]
            string GetData();

            [OperationContract]
            CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

            [OperationContract]
            [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionOnIPDWS))]
            [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/getAllServerMachines{poolingServer}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, Method = "GET")]
            //pServerName getAllServerMachines(string poolingServer); 
            string getAllServerMachines(string poolingServer); 

            [OperationContract]
            [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionOnIPDWS))]
            [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/getServerUtil", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
            Status getServerUtil(string poolingServer,string serverPID, ref string oCreateResult); 



            // TODO: Add your service operations here
        }
```

My php files look like this

```
<?php
$url = 'http://xomw764dei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getData';
//$url = func_get_arg(0);
$callback = $_GET["callback"];

echo($callback . "(");
    echo(file_get_contents($url));
echo (")");
?>



<?php
$url = 'http://xomw764dei/IPDWSRest/Service1.svc/getAllServerMachines';
//$url = func_get_arg(0);
$callback = $_GET["callback"];

echo($callback . "(");
echo(file_get_contents($url . '/' . $_POST["poolingServer"]));
echo (")");
?>
```

Now the first call in the browser works well
http://:1136/getData.php

But the second call does not return any data

http://:1136/ServerTools.php?poolingServer=thunderw7dei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UriTemplate should be like this:

```
[OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionOnIPDWS))]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/getAllServerMachines/{poolingServer}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, Method = "GET")]
        //pServerName getAllServerMachines(string poolingServer); 
        string getAllServerMachines(string poolingServer);
```